# INSERT statement to SYNONYM failing in SQL Server; any ideas?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, log4net

We have a C# WCF service application which uses log4net to log web service requests to a table. To offload traffic from customer data pulls, we have created a mirror of the master database and pointed our application at it. However, we need to ensure that log entries are written to the master database, so in the mirror, we drop the log table and replace it with a SYNONYM that points at the "real" table in the master DB.

Something weird is happening.

When pointed at the master database containing the real table, the INSERT statement works fine, and log entries get posted.

However, when pointed at the mirrored database containing the synonym pointing at the actual table, it appears the INSERT works (no exceptions), but the record never gets inserted.

We can see the actual statement being executed in SQL Profiler, and it's the same statement in both cases; however, one actually inserts a record, and the other does not.

Any ideas why the same code would work differently for inserting to a table versus a database synonym?

Things we have tried:

- We validated that INSERT statements against the SYNONYM work in SSMS: the record gets inserted in the master table.
- We tried pulling just the code to insert the record out and putting it in a second application. The insert works in this test application too, adding a record to the master table.
- We tried setting the UseTransactions property of the AdoNetAppender to false. Still worked against the real table, and did not work against the synonym.

We are out of ideas here. Help!

Schema of table in master database:

```
CREATE TABLE [Osha].[Log](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Process] [NVARCHAR](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Date] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [Thread] [NVARCHAR](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Level] [NVARCHAR](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL,
    [Logger] [NVARCHAR](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [User] [NVARCHAR](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RequestID] [NVARCHAR](36) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Event] [NVARCHAR](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Message] [NVARCHAR](MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Property] [NVARCHAR](MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Exception] [NVARCHAR](MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [O_Log_pk_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Synonym SQL:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [Osha].[Log] FOR [Test].[Osha].[Log]
```

SQL being executed against both:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert into [Osha].[Log] ([LastUpdatedBy], [Process], [Date], [Thread], [Level], [Logger], [User], [RequestID], [Event], [Message], [Property], [Exception]) values (1, ''d9a930b2-f29a-4764-89a0-1f3d7b6fb30a'', @Date, @Thread, @Level, @Logger, case when substring(@Message, 1, 5) = ''User:'' then substring(@Message, 7, charindex(char(13), @Message) - 7) else null end, case when substring(@Message, charindex(char(13), @Message) + 2, 10) = ''RequestID:'' then substring(@Message, charindex(char(13), @Message) + 13, 36) else null end, case when substring(@Message, charindex(char(13), @Message) + 51, 6) = ''Event:'' then substring(@Message, charindex(char(13), @Message) + 58, charindex(char(13), substring(@Message, charindex(char(13), @Message) + 59, 2147483647))) else null end, @Message, @Property, @Exception)',N'@Date datetime,@Thread nvarchar(255),@Level nvarchar(5),@Logger nvarchar(255),@Message nvarchar(max) ,@Property nvarchar(max) ,@Exception nvarchar(max) ',@Date='2018-09-20 16:32:44.663',@Thread=N'10',@Level=N'INFO',@Logger=N'blahblah',@Message=N'blahblach',@Property=N'{log4net:UserName=IIS APPPOOL\OshaTest, log4net:Identity=}',@Exception=N''
```

Here's the plan in the master database:

```
Clustered Index Insert(OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_pk_ID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_UserDateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_UserLevelDateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_RequestIDDateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_DateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_LevelDateID]), SET:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[LastUpdatedBy] = [Expr1003],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Process] = [Expr1004],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Date] = RaiseIfNullInsert([@Date]),[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Thread] = [Expr1005],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Level] = [Expr1006],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Logger] = [Expr1007],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[User] = [Expr1008],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[RequestID] = [Expr1009],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Event] = [Expr1010],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Message] = [@Message],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Property] = [@Property],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Exception] = [@Exception],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[ID] = [Expr1002],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Sequence] = RaiseIfNullInsert([Expr1011]),[Test].[Osha].[Log].[LastUpdated] = RaiseIfNullInsert([Expr1012]))) 0            0                         Clustered Index Insert Insert         OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_pk_ID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_UserDateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_UserLevelDateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_RequestIDDateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_DateID]), OBJECT:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[O_Log_ix_LevelDateID]), SET:([Test].[Osha].[Log].[LastUpdatedBy] = [Expr1003],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Process] = [Expr1004],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Date] = RaiseIfNullInsert([@Date]),[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Thread] = [Expr1005],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Level] = [Expr1006],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Logger] = [Expr1007],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[User] = [Expr1008],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[RequestID] = [Expr1009],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Event] = [Expr1010],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Message] = [@Message],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Property] = [@Property],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Exception] = [@Exception],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[ID] = [Expr1002],[Test].[Osha].[Log].[Sequence] = RaiseIfNullInsert([Expr1011]),[Test].[Osha].[Log].[LastUpdated] = RaiseIfNullInsert([Expr1012]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1            0.06         6E-006       9            0.0600075                                                                                                                                                        PLAN_ROW     0            1                  
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0            1            0            Top                    Top            TOP EXPRESSION:((1))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1            0            1E-007       1209         1.457E-006       [Expr1002], [Expr1003], [Expr1004], [Expr1005], [Expr1006], [Expr1007], [Expr1008], [Expr1009], [Expr1010], [Expr1011], [Expr1012]              PLAN_ROW     0            1                  
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=(1), [Expr1004]=N'7524a82f-a8f7-47bc-ad2c-2674dd3a2fb8', [Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),[@Thread],0), [Expr1006]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(25),[@Level],0), [Expr1007]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),[@Logger],0), [Expr1008]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],(1),(5))=N'User:' THEN substring([@Message],(7),charindex(N'
',[@Message])-(7)) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1009]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(36),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(2),(10))=N'RequestID:' THEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(13),(36)) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(51),(6))=N'Event:' THEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(58),charindex(N'
',substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(59),(2147483647)))) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1011]=[Test].[Osha].[CurrentSequence](), [Expr1012]=getdate()))                                                                                                                                                       0            2            1            Compute Scalar         Compute Scalar DEFINE:([Expr1003]=(1), [Expr1004]=N'7524a82f-a8f7-47bc-ad2c-2674dd3a2fb8', [Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),[@Thread],0), [Expr1006]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(25),[@Level],0), [Expr1007]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),[@Logger],0), [Expr1008]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],(1),(5))=N'User:' THEN substring([@Message],(7),charindex(N'
',[@Message])-(7)) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1009]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(36),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(2),(10))=N'RequestID:' THEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(13),(36)) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(51),(6))=N'Event:' THEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(58),charindex(N'
',substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(59),(2147483647)))) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1011]=[Test].[Osha].[CurrentSequence](), [Expr1012]=getdate())                                                                                                                                                         [Expr1003]=(1), [Expr1004]=N'7524a82f-a8f7-47bc-ad2c-2674dd3a2fb8', [Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),[@Thread],0), [Expr1006]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(25),[@Level],0), [Expr1007]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),[@Logger],0), [Expr1008]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],(1),(5))=N'User:' THEN substring([@Message],(7),charindex(N'
',[@Message])-(7)) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1009]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(36),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(2),(10))=N'RequestID:' THEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(13),(36)) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(250),CASE WHEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(51),(6))=N'Event:' THEN substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(58),charindex(N'
',substring([@Message],charindex(N'
',[@Message])+(59),(2147483647)))) ELSE NULL END,0), [Expr1011]=[Test].[Osha].[CurrentSequence](), [Expr1012]=getdate() 1            0            1E-007       1209         1.357E-006       [Expr1002], [Expr1003], [Expr1004], [Expr1005], [Expr1006], [Expr1007], [Expr1008], [Expr1009], [Expr1010], [Expr1011], [Expr1012]              PLAN_ROW     0            1                  
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1002]=getidentity((1408776126),(5),NULL)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0            3            2            Compute Scalar         Compute Scalar DEFINE:([Expr1002]=getidentity((1408776126),(5),NULL))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [Expr1002]=getidentity((1408776126),(5),NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1            0            1E-007       11           1.257E-006       [Expr1002]                                                                                                                                      PLAN_ROW     0            1                  
                 |--Constant Scan
```

I don't even see a plan in the mirror database...

Comment: Hypothesis: the synonym is/refers-to 'something else' in context. 1) Check the *default / connected schema* to see if a different synonym is being used. 2) Use [schema].[synonym] explicitly 3) See if data is written prior to TX close (eg. read without synonym)

Comment: The schemas are correct. If I insert into the synonym in SQL Server Managment Studio, the record gets inserted in the right table in the other database.

Comment: A mirror and a synonym are two completely different, unrelated technologies. What do you mean by mirror/synonym?  Also can you post the CREATE statements for the table and the synonym (or mirror) and the code you are using to insert.

Comment: I revised the description. I will add the SQL in a moment.

Comment: I'm starting to agree with @user2864740.  Could it be that the wpf app is running under a different userid that has a different default schema in the target db?  And that the insert statement is not a 2-part table name.  Or that there are permissions issues?  Are you getting error messages? (post them)

Comment: thanks for the sql.

Comment: We are using two part table names everywhere. I added the table definition, the synonym definition, and the actual query being executed against both databases.

Comment: The idea is that the SQL should be the same whether inserting against the table or the synonym....

Comment: Do you get an error (post it) when you target the synonym?

Comment: We are not getting any exceptions or errors of any kind. It just doesn't insert the record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180477/discussion-between-user1443098-and-jim-burnell).

Comment: Since you have SQL Profiler, use it to capture the estimated and actual query plans for both the original and synonym INSERTs.  Then either compare them or post them here.  Also, be sure you are capturing errors and statuses as well.

Answer (score 3):

There was an exception we were missing, which I found when I turned on error viewing in Profiler.

```
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Log', database 'TestMirror', schema 'Osha'.
```

I guess something was catching it and not passing it along to us.

Thanks to @RBarryYoung, @user2864740, and @user1443098 for your assistance.

Comment: So... the comment about the problem being different users/logins was correct, but it wasn’t the schema that was the issue but rather the permissions on the synonym.

Comment: Yep.  The problem is that client applications and/or their APIs to the database often “eat” the exceptions.